# Select2 - not working in bootstrap 3 with tabindex removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Select2 has this bug where it refuses to work properly in a Bootstrap 3 modal unless one removes the `tabindex` element from the modal. I have done so with several modals on my page and they all work, however, there is one where I cannot get Select2 to activate at all.

I have a list of department names and positions which is displayed in a table, each row has its own "EDIT" button that calls up the modal to display the record details. The `modal-body` is empty but upon load is populated via AJAX.

I am using another select2 field on the same page (not inside that modal, but the main table) which is working well, just the select2 in this modal doesnt seem to work...

My thought is that due to the AJAX interaction, I might have to refresh select2 or load it before / after the modal is populated, but neither has yielded any results so far.

Any suggestions please?

PHP

```
<!-- Modal EditDepartmentModal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="EditDepartmentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Department Record</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="SaveDepartmentButton" name="SaveDepartmentButton" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
        <button type="button" id="DeleteDepartmentButton" name="DeleteDepartmentButton" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Record</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.Modal EditDepartmentModal -->
```

AJAX:

```
<!-- JavaScript for Modal -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//Initialize Select2 Elements
$(function () {
    $(".select2").select2();
}); 

// VIEW DEPARTMENT RECORD                   
$('#EditDepartmentModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var modal = $(this);
    var dataDeptName = $(e.relatedTarget).data('dname');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php",
        data: { action:"view_department",Department_Name:dataDeptName}, // form data to post goes here as a json object
        //dataType: "html",
        //async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
    });

});
</script>
```

AJAX return:

```
echo "
    <!-- ID No. -->
    <label>ID No.:</label>
    <div class=\"input-group\">
        <span class=\"input-group-addon\"><i class=\"fa fa-database\"></i></span>
        <input type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"dataDeptID\" name=\"dataDeptID\" size=\"5\" value=\"$dept_id\" disabled />
    </div>
    <!-- /.id number -->                                        

    <p> </p>

    <!-- Department -->
    <label>Department Name:</label>
    <div class=\"input-group\">
        <span class=\"input-group-addon\"><i class=\"fa fa-bars\"></i></span>
        <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"dataDeptName\" name=\"dataDeptName\" value=\"$dept_name\" />
    </div>
    <!-- /.department -->

    <p> </p>

    <!-- Positions -->
    <label>Department Positions:</label>
    <div class=\"input-group\">
        <span class=\"input-group-addon\"><i class=\"fa fa-briefcase\"></i></span>
        <select class=\"form-control select2\" style=\"width:100%;\" id=\"test\" name=\"test\">
            <option value=\"1\">Option 1</option>
            <option value=\"2\">Option 2</option>
            <option value=\"3\">Option 3</option>
            <option value=\"4\">Option 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>";
```

The code is working alright, its just select2 that doesnt want to show up -.-

Comment: It look to me like you are trying to create select2 before the ajax containing the selectbox has even returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, if I read this right, the html is contained in the ajax return so you cannot call the select2 on it until after that so try this...

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //Initialize Select2 Elements
            $(function () {



            // VIEW DEPARTMENT RECORD
            $('#EditDepartmentModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
                var modal = $(this);
                var dataDeptName = $(e.relatedTarget).data('dname');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php",
                    data: { action:"view_department",Department_Name:dataDeptName}, // form data to post goes here as a json object
                    //dataType: "html",
                    //async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        modal.find('.modal-body').html(data);
                        $(".select2").select2();
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    },
                });

            });
      });
                </script>
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you so much! I would have never thought to initialize Select2 like this. Thanks a lot!